# Entering textfield values into an URL

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, mobile-safari

So I'm in the progress of developing an app but I'm kinda stuck at the moment. I have 2 textfields right now that the user will have to enter:

```
Ordernr:xxxxxxxx
Referencenr:xxxxxxx
```

these 2 values have to be added to this link:
http://www.artis-web.de/cgi-bin/WebObjects/Artis.woa/wa/detailedTrack?referencenr=xxxxxxxx&ordernr=xxxxxxxxxx

now I want safari to open this link. The ideal situation would be the user entering the 2 textfields values and then pressing a button called "open in safari"

What would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the following code to your button action:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.artis-web.de/cgi-bin/WebObjects/Artis.woa/wa/detailedTrack?referencenr=%@&ordernr=%@", referenceNrTextField.text, orderNrTextField.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
```

Comment: You are very welcome. Although I think ask4asif has a very good point in his post, I don't get why that is the accepted answer, since that didn't answer you question.

Answer (score 3):

To create the URL you can use...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.artis-web.de/cgi-bin/WebObjects/Artis.woa/wa/detailedTrack?referencenr=%@&ordernr=%@", referenceTextField.text, ordernoTextField.text]];
```

To open in safari...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the both fields have data and then hit the url with the given data.This condition would be sufficient.

```
 if (Ordernr.text.length!=0 && Referencenr.text.length!=0)
   {
      NSLog(@"Hit the Url with the entered data");
   }
   else
   {
    NSLog (@"Show Error Alert Message");
   }
```

Comment: Then Vote Up my Answer mate :)

Comment: just gained the access to upvoting ;)